# Nested strtok_r : command line argument parsing

Tags: c, linux

CODE HERE: http://ideone.com/AZnXFm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: %s",buffer);


    char *end_str,*token2;
    char *token = strtok_r(buffer,";",&end_str);
        printf("token : %s \n", token);
    int count =0,wordcnt=0;
    while(token !=NULL)
    {
        char *end_token;
        count++;
        printf("outside count ------------------------%d\n", count);
        strtok_r(token," ",&end_token);
        while(token2!=NULL)
        {
            wordcnt++;
            printf("insdie count %d\n",wordcnt);
            printf("%s------------------- \n", token2);
            token2 = strtok_r(NULL," ",&end_token);
        }
        token = strtok_r(NULL, ";",&end_str);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Output is

```
Type something: rosie is; really good
22 characters were read.
You typed: rosie is; really good
token : rosie is 
outside count ------------------------1
insdie count 1
AWAVA��AUATL�% ------------------- 
insdie count 2
is------------------- 
outside count ------------------------2
```

Comment: Please put the code here - in your question - not on an external site.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please put the code in in the actual question. And besides the actual output, please show the expected output. And if you haven't done it yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You're not capturing the result of the second `strtok_r()` at `strtok_r(token," ",&end_token);`.  You need: `token2 = strtok_r(token, " ", &end_token);`, don't you?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Also, you don't need to `malloc()` anything initially. Just set `buffer = NULL` and `bufsize = 0`, and `getline()` will do even the initial allocation for you.

Comment: The inner `while` loop checks an uninitialized `token2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of basic fixes are needed or have been applied in the code below:

- Let `getline()` do the memory allocation.
- Check that `getline()` read a line.
- Free the memory allocated.
- Set `token2` with inner `strtok_r()` call.
- Make variable names a bit more systematic.
- Make `characters` into `ssize_t` to match the return from `getline()`.
- Print `characters` using `%zd`.  This is marginally controversial; it prints the signed variant of `size_t` with the `z`-qualified signed decimal format string.  It makes sense (to me at least and my compiler — GCC 6.2.0 on macOS Sierra), but I'm not sure where to find the confirmation that it is officially sanctioned by (the POSIX) standards.
- Renaming variables for consistency.
- Other minor cosmetic fixups (the print formatting could still be improved — quite a lot).

Leading to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    ssize_t characters;

    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, stdin);
    printf("%zd characters were read.\n", characters);
    if (characters > 0)
    {
        printf("You typed: %s", buffer);

        char *end_str1;
        char *token1 = strtok_r(buffer, ";", &end_str1);
        printf("token: %s \n", token1);
        int count = 0, wordcnt = 0;
        while (token1 != NULL)
        {
            char *end_str2;
            count++;
            printf("outside count ------------------------%d\n", count);
            char *token2 = strtok_r(token1, " ", &end_str2);
            while (token2 != NULL)
            {
                wordcnt++;
                printf("inside count %d\n", wordcnt);
                printf("%s------------------- \n", token2);
                token2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &end_str2);
            }
            token1 = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &end_str1);
        }
    }
    free(buffer);

    return(0);
}
```

Example run:

```
Type something: rosie is; really good
22 characters were read.
You typed: rosie is; really good
token: rosie is 
outside count ------------------------1
inside count 1
rosie------------------- 
inside count 2
is------------------- 
outside count ------------------------2
inside count 3
really------------------- 
inside count 4
good
-------------------
```

Comment: POSIX does say `%zd` is for the signed type corresponding to `size_t`, but it does not say `ssize_t` is that type; `ssize_t` may be a larger type (because it should be able to represent both `-1` as well as all valid values of `size_t`). In practice, `ssize_t` == signed `size_t` on all implementations I've got a sniff of. On the other hand, casting `ssize_t` to `ptrdiff_t` and using `%td` to print it should be well defined, considering the definitions of `ssize_t` and `ptrdiff_t`. Me, I check for nonpositive (<0, ==0) separately, and print actual counts (>0) using `%zu` and a cast to `size_t`.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Your point about `ptrdiff_t` is interesting. I agree that in theory the code above could run foul of a devious implementation. I think in practice that the chances of running into such a devious implementation are small enough that I'm not going to worry about it — but I annotated the issue just in case anyone wants to be concerned about it. In the 64-bit world, it is going to be a while before anyone expects to write more than 2^63 bytes in a single write operation. What's that — 8 EiB in a single write? That's a large disk array — whether it's solid state or spinning disk!

Comment: I do think `%zd` will work in practice; only a language lawyer or somebody writing some unit testing or compile-time configuration testing code should care about `ptrdiff_t`; I'm just being too verbose here. Your notes above are definitely sufficient. ... However, the only non-`size_t` value in a `ssize_t` should be `-1` for errors, so testing the error case separately and using `%zu` for the `size_t`-cast value, is the common (expected?) way to do it -- perhaps POSIX devs thought so, too?

Comment: I guess I forgot to assign the token2... thanks for catching that!

Comment: And thank you so much for explaining so much.. I learnt a lot!